# max of octave sparse matrix failed

Tags: octave

I got a problem when using octave sparse matrix.

```
max(speye(65536)(:))
```

will result in a 0x0 variable.

However, `speye(65535)` and `speye(65537)` works. How that happens? My octave version is 3.2.4 in Fedora 14.

`max(max(speye(65536)))` gets the same result.

Comment: Same bug with octave 3.6.4

Comment: Bug report: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?40287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a quick response: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?40287

A fix is available, you could either wait for an update or compile a patched version of octave yourself.

Comment: It's my fault to not google it first. I just considered it as a rare bug.

Comment: There is another post about this bug.  http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=706376